# 2 Pair Ethernet not working

Tags: ethernet, wiring

I have one 4 pair cable. The brown pair is being used for a telephone (that is working). I took the green & orange pairs and punched those down to a CAT6 block and added a CAT6 connector at the wall alongside the existing phone.

My new (confirmed working) network tester is showing that pins 2 & 6 are connected. Pins 1 & 3 do not show continuity. If I move the solid G or O wire to different pins those show as continuous.

So, from wall to basement I have this:

Cat6 punch down adapter (T568A confirmed) using G/O pairs. That runs to the basement (toned out the correct cable) and the G/O pairs are punched down (T568A confirmed). From punch down block it runs to the back of an Airport Extreme Base Station (AEBS).

I understand this connection will only be 10/100Mb and that is fine; this is just for a roaming wifi network setup. Also of note; my Mac does recognize the cable and reports that it is 10Mb.

Also of note; I have used this wiring scheme with success in the same env. The only difference is that that line is using all 4 pairs (1000Mb)

My Mac shows that it is sending but not receiving any packets.

I've tried different (pre-made) cables and different punch down ports / adapters.

I have tried connecting the Blue pair as well with no change.
Halp.

Comment: This question would be better on Superuser.

Comment: It is likely the auto-negotiation process of the network adapter uses all 8 contacts as part of the process, and it fails because they are missing

Comment: I've done exactly this, but did not use a block. I used the blue pair for telephone and direct wired it. I used the orange and green for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet#100BASE-TX and direct wired those. Everything worked well.

Comment: Wires 1,2,3,6 are required for Ethernet to work correctly.  U also did thus with an additional two telephone lines.  I would test the block to make sure it is working correctly.  I would also put a laptop on the end and see if it connects properly.  It could be an issue with the airport.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell from your 4th paragraph if you are crossing over or not.

Automatic crossover detection is part of the  IEEE 802.3-2008 or IEEE 802.3ab  1000Base-T spec which uses all 4 pair. You don't have that so you do not get Automatic MDI/MDI-X. Make sure you terminate your orange and green for crossover as explained on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable.

Comment: Just tried 568A -> 568B with no luck. I also tried manually setting 100T (and 10T for that matter) with no luck either.